# how to return multiple columns in jooq update query using pair

Tags: java, sql, jooq

how to return multiple columns in jooq update query using pair?
 I have below query :

```
return jooq.build()
            .update(agentTable.TABLE)
            .set(agentTable.IS_ACTIVE, FALSE)            
            .where(agentTable.ORGANIZATION_ID.eq(organizationID)
            .returning(agentTable.WRITE_VERSION)
            .fetchOne()
            .into(Long.class);
```

Now I have requirement to return one more column agentName along with WRITE_VERSION column
 How will I achieve that in jooq?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the desired column to the returning clause:

```
.returning(agentTable.AGENT_NAME, agentTable.WRITE_VERSION)
```

And then call

```
.fetchOne() // Don't call .into(Long.class) on that
```

You can then map the resulting record into your own data type after a `null` check